# Open file with specific program via batch script within program that is already open

Tags: windows, batch-file

I figured out that I could open a file with a specific program with the following batch skeleton code:

```
START "" <PROGRAM EXE> <FILE>
```

My question is, if the program denoted by "PROGRAM EXE" is already open (prior to running the batch script), is there a way for the batch script to make the program open the file into the window that is already open and not into a new window/instance of the program? For reference, the program I am using is JMP and I am opening a CSV file.

Just makes things less cluttered.

Comment: Only if `PROGRAM EXE` was written to support this; if it was what you have would probably work.  You should look at the command line options available for the exe to see if it supports another method.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was directed to me from a JMP discussion forum, utilizing the "/shellopen" parameter.

```
START "" /shellopen <PROGRAM EXE> <FILE>
```